# Uniqueness of cauchy problem $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \Delta u + u^2(x, t) = f(x, t), \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^N, 0 < t< T$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the Cauchy problem

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \Delta u + u^2(x, t) = f(x, t), x \in \mathbb{R}^N, 0 < t< T$$
$$u(x, 0) = 0$$

Prove the uniqueness of the classical bounded solution assuming that $T$ is small enough.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. The maximum principle won't work since the domain is infinite. Energy estimates usually consider a homogenous version of this problem by considering the difference between solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$. However, because of the $u^2$ term, taking the difference between two solutions doesn't give a homogenized version of the same PDE.

Comment: $$\|u_1^2 - u_2^2\| \leq \left\|u_1 - u_2\right\| (\left\|u_1\right\| + \left\|u_2\right\|)$$ so if you can prove that $u$ remains bounded for small times, energy estimates will work.